# save into multiple textfile in c#

Tags: c#

i have code below...this code suppose to do this.

1- create a textfile file, with the same name like textfile in folder "inputText" and save it in folder "outputText".

2-then, write all term from dictionary.Keys into it..

i can create all the textfile, but. my problem is, when to write it. The output save in D:\DGA\outputText\article2, contain the combination output from article1 and article2.. same goes to article3.. it contain the combination output from article1, article2 and article3..thus, if i have 100 article... article100 will contain the combination output from article1 until article100.. can u help me find the solution?

i just want, article2 will save output from article2 only, article3 will save output from article3 and so on..

thnks!

```
       string fileInputTextName = name; // name = articles name eg, article1,article2 from folder "inputText"
       string filename1 = Path.GetFileName(fileInputTextName);


       string dir = @"D:\\DGA\inputText";
       string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir);

       string Dir = @"D:\\DGA\outputText";
       var newpath = Dir + "\\" + filename1;
       Console.WriteLine("file name: " + newpath);


       StreamWriter log1;

       if (!File.Exists(@newpath))
       {
          log1 = new StreamWriter(@newpath);
       }
       else
       {
          log1 = File.AppendText(@newpath);
       }

       foreach (string term in dictionary.Keys)
       {
           log1.WriteLine(term);
       }

       // Close the stream:
       log1.Close();
```

Comment: `2-then, write all term from dictionary.Keys into it..` so essentially the problem is that `dictionary.Keys` is not getting reset?

Comment: yeah.. i think so.. do u have any solution about it?